# Linux RADIUS logs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, authentication, centos

I have a program called Radius which authenticates user login. It is running on CentOS server

The logs are in /var/log/radius.log

They are as follow

```
Mon Jul 24 22:17:08 2017 : Auth: Login incorrect: [faaiz.aleem] (from client PTCL-VPN port 28 cli 116.213.34.97) DeviceIP: 192.168.30.101
Mon Jul 24 23:32:41 2017 : Auth: Login OK: [muhammad.razzaq] (from client PTCL-VPN port 29 cli 45.116.233.62) DeviceIP: 192.168.30.101
Tue Jul 25 03:06:08 2017 : Auth: Login OK: [sadiq.akhter] (from client devices port 1 cli 192.168.141.1) DeviceIP: 1.8.3.11
Tue Jul 25 03:07:54 2017 : Auth: Login OK: [sadiq.akhter] (from client devices port 1 cli 10.88.33.2) DeviceIP: 1.6.16.1
Tue Jul 25 09:44:39 2017 : Auth: Login incorrect: [shariq.iqbal] (from client devices port 1 cli 10.10.10.173) DeviceIP: 1.6.10.11
```

Now I want to sort them out for each user for e.g sadiq.akhter against last login made by them. Please suggest a good bash script or Linux command to do so. I shall be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick solution to get only lines with a defined user (and write to a file):

```
grep "USERNAME" /var/log/radius.log > log_for_user.log
```

the last line you get from grep should be the last login record.

you can use **tac** to print your log file in reverse order and use **"grep -m1 .."** to get only one (the last) match.

returns the last line with USERNAME inside your log:

```
tac /var/log/radius.log | grep -m1 "USERNAME"
```

So in a shell script it can look like this, returns you all recent entries to all users:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat USERLIST`
do
    tac LOGFILE | grep -m1 $i
done
```

where **USERLIST** is a file lists all usernames, separated by newline and **LOGFILE** is your radius logfile.

Comment: Actually there are 400 unique users and I cant do that, my boss asks me to provide list of user who are inactive in just 10 minutes

Comment: okay.. if you have a user list you can do.  if not you may can use **awk**, but i can't help you with awk.

Comment: With user list it will take around 2-3 hour even if copy paste each user to grep command. My boss wants it in 10 minutes. I have tried many awk example but no success yet.

Comment: right... you have to build up a (shell) script calling grep with each username.

Comment: can you guide me shell script please.

Comment: i am at work now... may later in the evening. do you have a  user list/which format ?

Comment: i added a short script above, try it.

Comment: Thanks a lot so I will have to enter users like sadiq.akhter and shariq.iqbal and 400 other like for i in `cat sadiq.akhter,shariq.iqbal`  and do
    tac radius.log | grep -m1 $i
done

Comment: make a text file and write your usernames in there. line by line. replace USERLIST with the filename (path)  to that file.

Comment: Excellent it works for each user I am getting this out put


Thu Jul 27 16:18:52 2017 : Auth: Login OK: [maqsood.ahmed] (from client devices port 317 cli 10.10.10.40) DeviceIP: 172.16.100.254
Thu Jul 27 15:37:11 2017 : Auth: Login OK: [shariq.iqbal] (from client devices port 1 cli 10.10.10.173) DeviceIP: 1.6.0.20
Mon Jul 24 09:21:43 2017 : Auth: Login OK: [raheel.khan] (from client devices port 1 cli 10.10.10.252) DeviceIP: 10.2.100.103





Now can I sort the output with date and also I want to output this to file. I hope you can help.